# File created in package doesn't exist in other Elixir app using said package

Tags: file, package, elixir

So I just built this package, and it's not running properly when used in a different Elixir app. A config file I created in the package repository, doesn’t exist it seems when I install it in a different Elixir app.

https://github.com/sergiotapia/curltime

```
`Warning: Failed to read config/curl-format.txt`
```

But that file is here: https://github.com/sergiotapia/curltime/blob/master/config/curl-format.txt

---

Is there a way to make sure this file exists when my curltime package is installed anywhere?

Comment: You can pass in `"@" <> Path.expand("../config/curl-format.txt", __DIR__)` as the path. It should work but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this.

Comment: Hm... I'll just use a plain string, and not a format file for curltime. Strange though!

Comment: Not really strange. `System.cmd` will set the current directory to the project that's including `curltime`, and you're passing a relative path, so it get resolved to `thatproject/config/curl-format.txt`, which doesn't exist. A string is probably better anyways as it's not too long.

Comment: Thank you @Dogbert appreciate the info

Answer (score 0):

In `package` in `mix.exs` you specified list of files, which will be attached to Hex. Now it looks like `files: ["lib", "mix.exs", "README*", "LICENSE*"]`.

You didn't attached the whole `config` folder. Consider moving this txt file somewhere else.

Comment: I moved the file to `lib/curl-format.txt` and republished to Hex.pm, still get `Warning: Failed to read lib/curl-format.txt` - https://github.com/sergiotapia/curltime/commit/bcdae38074a7a46197a55decc7e5e3a228cb16e2